# Why CoordinatorLayout not found on my project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-coordinatorlayout

Before I published it here, I searched a lot, but I could not find a solution.

why CoordinatorLayout not found on my project ?

*screenshot*

[image]

*gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.salah250.forvo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //Material Design
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    //GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    //Event Bus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //Butter knife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    //Circle Image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

I hope to find a solution to this problem..............................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you checked the dependencies (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1`) and in the layout which starts by: **`androidx.coordinatorlayout`** It means **you're still using Support Library dependencies** but you are trying to use `AndroidX` `CoordinatorLayout`.

Use `Migrate to AndroidX` from `Refactor` or, use Support Library `CoordinatorLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Read:** https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 0):

There are some pre-requisities for setting up AndroidX. You can find some of them in the [Using AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/) section of the documentation as well as in the [Migrate an existing project using Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

The first and only thing I can notice from the snippet you have provided, you have not set the `compileSdkVersion` to 28, but please check the links that I have provided you with. There may be more to it.

Comment: compileSdkVersion was 28 but I changed to 27 because not working

Comment: Try to have `compileSdkVersion 28` in your gradle file and 
`android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true` 
in your `gradle.properties` file.

If this doesn't work, refer to the documentation for more.

Comment: @NiravKotecha happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

just put these two lines in your gradle.properties -file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Do a gradle sync and you're set :)

Comment: where inside what ?

Comment: You have a file named gradle.properties in your project's folder. You have to add the mentioned lines here, make a gradle sync and after this you should find CoordinatorLayout with androidX